# Dynamic page-based Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

I tried to create a page-based Apple Watch app.

As far as I can see, you can create a fixed number of pages for your app in the storyboard.

So I just wonder if there is any way to dynamically programmatically create the pages for your app based on the loaded data?

I.e: a newspaper app in which users can swipe left and right to switch to different articles.

Thanks

Comment: have u got the solution??

Comment: @BandishDave I haven't got a chance to come back to this problem but last time I checked, there was no perfect solution.

Answer (score 11):

You can present page based navigation from code. You can specify as many pages as you want, but those pages has to be designed in the Storyboard

```
func presentControllerWithNames(names: [AnyObject], contexts: [AnyObject]?) // modal presentation of paged controllers. contexts matched to
```

**Example**

Present `Page` Interfaces for objects. This code show page for every object

```
let objects  = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let controllers = Array(count: objects.count, repeatedValue: "Page")
presentControllerWithNames(controllers, contexts: objects)
```

Present different Interface for different object object.

```
let objects  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let controllers = objects.map { object  in object % 2 == 0 ? "Even-Page" : "Odd-Page" }
presentControllerWithNames(controllers, contexts: objects)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it worked. But the method actually displays a page-based modal view, therefore there is a Cancel button on the screen. Is there any way we can remove that Cancel button and make our own button instead?

Comment: No, there isn't. At least at the moment @LeonNguyen

Comment: @LeonNguyen As temporary workaround you can call [self setTitle:""] on the WKInterfaceController you present. This will change the Cancel button to an empty string but it will continue to be selectable unfortunately. Also in the current beta 5 doing this you will see the Cancel button for a second while the controller appears. To make it completely invisible you have to set the "Title" field in IB to a space string.

Comment: Its just add-on to this answer.
Please refer to this link:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/WatchKit_Page-based_User_Interfaces_and_Modal_Interface_Controllers

Answer (score 7):

In root interface controller's awakeWithContext method, use WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames class method.

```
let objects  = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let controllers = Array(count: objects.count, repeatedValue: "Page")
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(controllers, contexts: objects)
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Do I need to manually add Interface controllers in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get these answers to work because I was missing an important part, you need to create a second interface controller with its identifier as the controller name. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955247/945247