# Page Based "reloadRootControllersWithNames:" on launch loop?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
[super awakeWithContext:context];
    [WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"pageOne", @"pageTwo"] contexts:nil];
}
```

Following Apple's guidelines

> Call this method to reload the pages in your app’s page-based interface. At launch time, you use this method to customize the set of pages you want displayed.

at launch time, only results in a loop. With each reload calling awakeWithContext or will Activate or init again and again.

Is there a better way to go about reloading the Page-Based app on launch with a loop occurring?

Comment: awakewithcontext is called every time you call reloadRootControllersWithNames, thats why it result in a loop. Just configure your default page-base navigation  in the storyboard

Comment: Yes, I read Apple's docs incorrectly perceiving at launch time it was suppose to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a common problem with WatchKit apps since we no longer have a `UIApplicationDelegate` to handle such set up. A good approach would be to structure your code as follows:

- `MainInterfaceController` (the main link in storyboard points here)
- `PageOneInterfaceController` - your first interface to display in the page set
- `PageTwoInterfaceController` - your second interface in the page set

The `MainInterfaceController` will never actually get displayed. You will always launch into a different set of interface controllers depending on the cached state of the companion iOS App in `MainInterfaceController.awakeWithContent()`. This way, you use the `MainInterfaceController` in a similar manner that we use the `UIApplicationDelegate` in iOS to set up the window and root view controller.

I have used this approach in an app that had many different page sets to choose from and it worked very well.

Comment: Wow brilliant, that's a clever workout, I was about to use a bunch of booleans and not looking forward to it. Thanks a many!

Comment: reloadRootControllersWithNames - this does not call deactivate on the controllers that were already present. Any solutions if something needs to be stopped (like a timer) on the controller that was visible?

Comment: @cnoon Ive been using this to present the correct WKInterface Controller from a remote notification. I end up calling `reloadRootControllersWithNames` twice once in `awakeWithContext` of my `MainInterfaceController` and once in `- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification`. However i see three dots in the page control at first which then becomes two. Any way to avoid that? Am i approaching this the correct way?

Answer (score 6):

That is why `awakeWithContext:` exists. The first time your app is launched, the initial controller is passed `nil` as `context`. But if you `reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:`, you have an opportunity to pass a custom context instance and thus distinguish the launch mode.

Comment: This is a much simpler and cleaner approach, thanks!

Comment: This is how I implement mine as well!

Answer (score 0):

calling WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers causes the awake function to be called a second time.  This is the solution I use - it is straight forward, compact, and eliminates the recursive loop.  This example has two page based views called mainControls and nowPlaying that are configured with contexts.  Note the key thing here is to configure the mainControls view controller with an empty string context then that context is checked and returns if it is being called again due to the WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers statement that configured the context to "".  Note the first time awake runs the context for the main view controller will be nil. Also note the second context is an implementation detail specific to my implementation - this could be any object that you want to pass to the second view controller.

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    if let _ = context as? String {
        print("already configured!")
        return
    }
    print("configuring...")
    WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["mainControls", "nowPlaying"], contexts: ["", interaction])
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Really easy to solve, and does not require Multiple Page Controllers -- Just use once

Create a class variable (not an instance variable) and use that as your flag to ensure that your call to reloadRootControllers is only ever called once.

```
static NSString* hasLaunchedIfNotNullString = NULL;

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context
{
    if(hasLaunchedIfNotNullString == NULL)
    {
        //START Code which gets executed once
        hasLaunchedIfNotNullString = @"";

        ...
        [WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:YOUR_ARRAY contexts:CONTEXTS];
        // END code which gets executed once
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a string field as a flag is generally a bad idea.