# How to reuse WKInterfaceTable in WatchKit

Tags: xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I chose page-based layout for my WatchKit app. Each page shows a table. I want to keep the layout of the table exactly the same across all pages. I will be feeding filtered data to each page at run time, so essentially pages will be identical, except the data will be different.

[image]

One way to achieve this is to manually create InterfaceController instance for each page in InterfaceBuilder, then populate with GUI elements and connect the outlets. The problem here is whenever I want to change something (say, move a label or add a button), I will have to apply that change consistently to every page.

Moreover, for each page I have to connect the outlets to table row controller, essentially repeating myself over and over again. Here's an illustration:

[image]

Is there a way to reuse a table?

I considered inheritance, but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html) tells me not to subclass WKInterfaceTable. This also rules out creating a table programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a single interface controller with the table and various row types. Then you want to create an architecture very similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955247/1342462). You'll only have a single `PageOneInterfaceController` which should be named `TableInterfaceController` in this example with `TableInterfaceIdentifier` as the identifier. Then you would do the following:

**MainInterfaceController.swift**

```
func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    let context1 = "context 1 - for you to fill out"
    let context2 = "context 2 - for you to fill out"
    let context3 = "context 3 - for you to fill out"

    WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(
        ["TableInterfaceIdentifier", "TableInterfaceIdentifier", "TableInterfaceIdentifier"], 
        contexts: [context1, context2, context3]
    )
}
```

This will reload the page set using the same interface controller that displays all the data in the respective context.

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks for jumping in.

Comment: Awesome. @bgilham: I see that you were saying essentially the same thing, but it *really* helps to have an example.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this, provide the same `WKInterfaceController` in `reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:` multiple times, but provide a different context to each one.

Comment: Does it work with page-based interface? Could you point me to an example? I am reading the doc "Interface Navigation", and it looks like what you are suggesting will only work with hierarchical interface.